# How to set the text color of a textobject using reportlab pdfgen

Tags: python, pdf-generation, reportlab

I was recently looking for the function needed to set a `textobject`'s text color. The `textobject` is a specific method of working with `reportlab`'s `pdfgen`. The documentation has some information, but it's pretty unclear.

Starting code:

```
textobject = canvas.beginText()
textobject.textOut("Example Text")
canvas.drawText(textobject)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `setFillColorRGB()` function to change the color. The function takes 3 values (red, green, blue) and expects the values to be 0-1.

Example:

```
textobject = canvas.beginText()
textobject.setFillColorRGB(0.5, 0.5, 0.5) #grey text
textobject.textOut("Example Text")
canvas.drawText(textobject)
```